# Easier way to build forms with VB.NET than creating windows forms from scratch?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm a novice developer in VB.NET.

When I build forms I find myself spending a lot of time positioning the different controls. If I later decide to remove a control at the top, I have to move all controls up in the form to make it look good again. This work process feels inefficient to me.

I have built web pages using Wordpress. In Wordpress, other people have built great plugins that I can use, like Gravity Forms. With Gravity forms I just drag the controls to approximately where I want them and it automatically takes care of spacing and things like that. If I remove a control at the top of my form, all controls below are automatically moved up.

Are there similar kinds of "plugins" that other have created that I can use so that creating forms more efficiently?

Comment: You can simulate more HTML type layout using `FlowLayoutPanal` or `TableLayoutPanel`. You might try mocking up your design on paper or wire-framing in balsamiq first before you create your form in Visual Studio. That may reduce the work associated with tweaking your form in the designer.

Comment: [Measure twice, cut once](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/measure_twice_and_cut_once)

Comment: @Plutonix It's still too short.  Better cut it again.

Comment: Use various panels as containers for your controls and make use of the panel's docking capabilities (top, left, right, bottom, fill) in your forms. Once panels are docked, hiding controls, removing them, or repositioning them is quick and easy. For example, hiding/removing top-docked controls will move other docked controls up automatically. This will also ensure your program looks the same when viewed at different resolutions...which may cause issues if you rely on manually positioning controls.

Comment: @Plutonix What happens if the size of the thing changes in between measurements?